# Sorting Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding

I have A listview which I want to sort.
My problem is that when I click the sorting column the Onsorting event only fires when I Bind the data on pageload again.
This means that on every pageload I will first have to bind the data, then I can catch the OnBinding event and after that I can Rebind the data again. 
Is there a better way to do this. Basically what I want is to bind the data only in the onsorting event

```
<asp:ListView ID="TempList" runat="server" OnSorting="TempList_sorting">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table >
            <tr>
                <th >
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSortVoorletters2" CommandName="Sort" Text="Voorletters"
                        CommandArgument="Voorletters" OnClick="btnSortVoorletters_Click" />
                </th>
            </tr>
              <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="EmpIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Naam") %>'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate> 
    <p>Empty text that will be displayed.</p> 
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It lloks that you're always binding in `PageLoad` so that the previously supplied order is lost. Bind only if `IsPostback` is false. (You need to have the ListView `EnableViewState` set to true, which is the default value).

```
 if(!IsPostback)
 {
   // do the binding
 }
```

When the user clicks the 'Sort' button, the event will be fired and your event will sort and bind the data accordingly.

If the page is reloaded, and you don't rebind it in `PageLoad` this will be enough.

However, if for some reason you really need to rebind in `PageLoad`, what you have to do is to store the sorting in `ViewState`, a `HiddenField` or `Session` so that you can get the value from there to sort the data before binding it in `PageLoad`.

You should take the code that sorts and binds to a new method, and call it from both the Sort and the `PageLoad` events.

Comment: Hi there,Thanks it works when I set viewstate enabled. the only thing is that this client doesn't want to have viewstate enabled, because of the large volume that it can ahve. Isn't it commen to disable viewstate because of this reason/ I alwasys thought that you shouldn't use it thanks for the response